# Intuition for Riemannian submersions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, intuition

> **Definition:** A submersion $f:M\to N$ between Riemannian manifolds is called a **Riemannian submersion** if for each $p\in M$,  $d_pf:(\ker d_pf)^\perp\to T_{f(p)}N$ is an isometry.

In contrast to  Riemannian immersions I find it difficult to get an intuitive understanding of what Riemannian submersions  are. At the moment I think of them as something  like  orthogonal projections but I am not sure if this intuition is always correct.

So my questions are:

$\bullet$ How can one think of  Riemannian submersions?

$\bullet$ What nice properties do Riemannian submersions have in contrast to arbitrary submersions?

Comment: @C.F.G I hardly think that is a worthwhile edit after almost 3 years.

Comment: @TedShifrin: It is good to answer such posts to remove them from unanswered list.

Comment: @C.F.G If we had a good answer, presumably we would have answered without your trivial edit. My only answer offhand would be about frame bundles.

Comment: @TedShifrin: any answer is better than no answer. (In most cases)

Comment: I agreed with Ted: This is a hard question to get hold of. It's more natural to me to reverse things: We start with a fibre bundle over a Riemannian manifold $p:E \to (M, g)$ and obtain a Riemannian submersion by constructing a metric on $E$ of the form "$p^*g$ plus metrics on the fibres," or we notice that a particular metric (such as Fubini-Study on complex projective space, mapping to a suitable round sphere) arises this way.